# Как передать пареметр в библиотечную функцию ?

Tags: c#, dll

Моя задача:

---

Для вычисления значений по формуле (60*1,5^(значение TextBox-1)), которая находится в библиотеке и описывается так:

```
public class Cost
{
    public static int Cost_Of_MetalMine(int MM_Metal, int MM_Silicon)
    {
        return MM_Metal = (int)(60 * Math.Pow(1.5,значение TextBix - 1));
    }
}
```

мне необходимо передать значение TextBox`а в формулу. Я пытаюсь сделать все это через делегат,
обьявляю в библиотеке:

```
namespace SCore
{
    public delegate int GetComboboxindex(int SelectedIndex);
    ...
    ...
}
```

Выоношу метод получения значения TextBox`а в отдельный класс:

```
namespace Sim
{
    class Operations
    {
        public static void MFD_GetSelectedIndex(int SI_LevelOfBuilding, int SI_NameOfBuilding)
        {
            KalkulatorStoimosti chc = new KalkulatorStoimosti();
            SI_LevelOfBuilding = int.Parse(chc.LevelOfSelectedBuilding.Text);
            // TextBox
            SI_NameOfBuilding = chc.SelectedIndexOfBuilding.SelectedIndex;
            // ComboBox
        }
    }
}
```

И передаю его:

```
namespace Sim
{
    public partial class KalkulatorStoimosti : Form
    {
    public int SI_LevelOfBuilding;
    public int SI_NameOfBuilding;
        public KalkulatorStoimosti()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            GetComboboxindex Get_Combobox_Index_Method = Operations.MFD_GetSelectedIndex(SI_LevelOfBuilding,SI_NameOfBuilding);
            Core.CoreMethod(Get_Combobox_Index_Method);
        }
    }
}
```

Библиотека принимает:

```
public static void CoreMethod (GetComboboxindex CallBackFinction_GetIndex)
{
    CallBackFinction_GetIndex();
}
```

Я недописал передаваемые аргументы в функции потому как запутлся...т.к тут:

```
GetComboboxindex Get_Combobox_Index_Method = Operations.MFD_GetSelectedIndex(SI_LevelOfBuilding,SI_NameOfBuilding);
```

пишет: неявное преобразование void в int невозможно. Исправить данную ситуацию я не понимаю как. Перепробовал все что знал ...
Обьясните, по правильному пути ли я иду ? Правильно ли делаю ? Как все таки передать мне значение TxtBox`а в библиотечную функцию ?...

---

**UPD1**:
[[@Flammable](/users/10467/flammable)](/users/10467/flammable), спасибо за помощь, хотел бы еще спросить,
как прикрутуть switch к библиотечному методу ? нужна инициализация переменных для передачи, но используя switch переменные инициализируются  лишь в нем что не right. Как лучше поступить ?
[[@alexlz](/users/352/alexlz)](/users/352/alexlz), спасибо за инфу. Попробую после того как разберусь с этой проблемой. Заинтересовало ;)
Заранее спросить хочу, что продуктивнее передача параметра в функцию или использование

```
tuple<T,T>`
```

Библиотечная функция:

```
public static void Cost_Of_SelectedBuiding(out int MM_Metal, out int MM_Silicon, int SI_LevelOfBuilding, int SI_SelectedComboboxIndex)
        {
            //MM_Metal = (int)(60 * Math.Pow(1.5, SI_LevelOfBuilding - 1));
            //MM_Silicon = (int)(15 * Math.Pow(1.5, SI_LevelOfBuilding - 1));

            switch (SI_SelectedComboboxIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    MM_Metal = (int)(60 * Math.Pow(1.5, SI_LevelOfBuilding - 1));
                    MM_Silicon = (int)(15 * Math.Pow(1.5, SI_LevelOfBuilding - 1));
                    break;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ух... Внутри MFD_GetSelectedIndex ты выполняешь присваивания локальным переменным. Очевидно, что никаких данных из него ты не получишь. Если необходимо вернуть SI_LevelOfBuilding и SI_NameOfBuilding, следует использовать передачу параметров по ссылке с помощью ключевых слов ref/out:

```
public static void MFD_GetSelectedIndex(out int SI_LevelOfBuilding, out int SI_NameOfBuilding)
{
    KalkulatorStoimosti chc = new KalkulatorStoimosti();
    SI_LevelOfBuilding = int.Parse(chc.LevelOfSelectedBuilding.Text);
    // TextBox
    SI_NameOfBuilding = chc.SelectedIndexOfBuilding.SelectedIndex;
    // ComboBox
}
```

Вообще это Bad design. Неудивительно, что запутался.
Объяви библиотечный метод так:

```
public static int Cost_Of_MetalMine(int MM_Metal, int MM_Silicon, int bindingLevel)
{
    return MM_Metal = (int)(60 * Math.Pow(1.5, bindingLevel - 1));
}
```

и вызывай как-нибудь так:

```
var bindingLevel = int.Parse(chc.LevelOfSelectedBuilding.Text);
var cost = Cost_Of_MetalMine(MM_Metal, MM_Silicon, bindingLevel);
```

Comment: Провел еще час в бестолковых попытках правки своего кода. Но все равно не понял что к чему. 
@Flammable, можешь на пальцах обьяснить на счет вызова ? 
Ругается на на этот код, передающий значние TB в библиотечную функцию:
GetComboboxindex GCBI = Operations.MFD_GetSelectedIndex(out SI_LevelOfBuilding, out SI_NameOfBuilding); на счет преобразования void в int

Comment: Давай сначала. Как я это все понимаю: у тебя есть библиотека, которая содержит какой-то метод. Тебе нужно передать в этот метод int, полученный из текста текстбокса. Так?

Comment: Да. Так и есть.

Comment: Ну так и делай:

var textBoxValue = Convert.ToInt32(textBox.Text);
var result = ExternalLibraryMethod(textBoxValue);

textBox - твой текстбокс, ExternalLibraryMethod - библиотечный метод.

Comment: вроде с этим разобрался.. только вот вопрос: у меня метод должен принимать один параметр и передавать два т.е если я буду указывать так: Cost.Cost_Of_MetalMine(0, 0, Convert.ToInt32(chc.LevelOfSelectedBuilding.Text)); то у меня будут возвращены указанные занчения ?

Comment: Передавай их с модификаторами ref/out, тогда будут возвращены.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ee332485.aspx

Comment: Все у меня уже не хватило нервов. http://ideone.com/t4hiVn
Помогите правильно вывести значения...
насколько я понимаю, для одного метода существует одно возвращаемое значение ? тогда как мне поступить если нужно возвратить несколько значений ?

Comment: Читай мануалы по ссылке, там с примерами все показано.
Вот тебе еще пример: http://pastebin.com/x4niUPrD

Comment: Можно параметры передавать по ссылке, как советует @Flammable, а результаты передавать по этим ссылкам "в зад" (или "взад") (незаметно для неопытного читателя, почти тайком). А если попробовать возвращать не int а Tuple<int, int>? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx. Т.е. тип метода Tuple<int, int>